# How many integers from $1$ through $1000$ are not divisible by any one of $4, 5$, and $6$?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I hate to use this resource as an argument settler but my friend and I have come across this question and we cannot agree on an answer.

I got $500$ through the use of inclusion and exclusion and he got $466$ through the use of gathering LCM's and such.

Who is correct?

Comment: Neither of you are correct.

Comment: could you explain what "the use of gathering LCM's and such" means?

Comment: It’s rather interesting that his answer was exactly the real answer taken away from $1000$...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inclusion Exclusion makes more sense to me than "the use of gathering LCM's and such"

But you do need LCM to do inclusion exclusion.

There are $1000$ integers.  $250$ divisible by $4$ and $200$ by $5$ and $166$ by $6$.  There are $1000/20 = 50$ there are divisible by both $4$ and $5$ (divisible by $4$ and $5$ means divisible by $20$).  But to be divisible by both $4$ and $6$ means to be divisible by $12$, not $24$ so there are $83$ divisible by both $4$ and $6$. And $33$ by both $6$ and $5$.  And to be divisible by all $3$ is to be divisible by $60$ and there are $16$ of those.

So the answer is $1000 - 250 - 200 - 166 + 50 + 83 + 33 - 16 = 534$.

Answer (score 4):

Let A,B,C be the sets of integers between $1$ and $1000$ (inclusive) which are divisible $4,5,6$.  We want $|(A\cup B\cup C)^c|$

Now $$|(A\cup B\cup C)|=|A|+|B|+|C|-|A\cap B|-|B\cap C|-|A\cap C|+|A\cap B\cap C|$$

Now find $$|A|=\lfloor\dfrac{1000}{4}\rfloor=?$$
$$|B|=\lfloor\dfrac{1000}{5}\rfloor=?$$
$$|C|=\lfloor\dfrac{1000}{6}\rfloor=?$$
$$|A\cap B|=\lfloor\dfrac{1000}{20}\rfloor=?$$
and so on .....

Comment: Im pretty sure this is what I did

Comment: @DevAllanPer Then show us your workings and we might help you to find your mistake

Comment: First part total was: 616 Second Part: 124 and Third Part: 8 so if now by Inclusion/Exclusion 1000-616+124-8 = 500

Comment: @DevAllanPer  For the intersections, you have to use the least common multiple rather than the product.

Comment: Could you extend your explanation on that, Im not sure why LCM would be relevant if the I/E formula should be able to eliminate repeats. I feel like using the LCM would eliminate repeats twice over.

Comment: @DevAllanPer Consider the common multiples of $4$ and $6$.  They are $12, 24, 36, 48, \ldots$.  Notice that they are the common multiples of $\textrm{lcm}(4, 6) = 12$.  In general, the set of common multiples of integers $m$ and $n$ is $\textrm{lcm}(m,n)$.

Comment: $4*6$ will eliminate those divisible a multiple of $6$ four times and the multiples of $4$ six times but not the mulitiple of $6$ two times (which are a multiple of $4$) or the mulitples of $4$ three times (which are multiples of $6$)